# Good strategy to pass complicated data structure to fragment or activity

Tags: android

Currently, to pass complicated data structure to a fragment or an activity, I'm using the strategy described by http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

> You can also use a HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects with Long
>   keys. When an activity wants to pass an object to another activity, it
>   simply puts the object in the map and sends the key (which is a unique
>   Long based on a counter or time stamp) to the recipient activity via
>   intent extras. The recipient activity retrieves the object using this
>   key.

I use `Application` to hold the global accessible `HashMap`, and use the following code to send across Long key.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    public static MyFragment newInstance(long myArrayId) {
        // This is how I receive the object Id.
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putLong(MyApplication.INTENT_EXTRA_MY_ARRAY_ID, myArrayId);
        myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // This is how I turn Id into Object.
        this.myArrayIdId = this.getArguments().getLong(MyApplication.INTENT_EXTRA_MY_ARRAY_ID);
        this.myArray = (MyArray)MyApplication.instance().getExtra(myArrayIdId );
```

I first thought this is a pretty good strategy. Especially for those complicated data structure, which seems impossible, to implement using `Parcelable`.

This strategy works pretty well **most of the time**. However, there is situation where it doesn't work. I just find out that, it is possible for the system to destroy `Application`, if it isn't activated for some time.

This is how to reproduce the problem.

1. Run your app
2. Press Home
3. Run other memory intensive app by running them, pressing Home, running the others again.
4. Long press on Home button. Your app should still appear in the list.
5. Select it. You will realize the object `HashMap` is empty. (Following by application crashes, as we get null object)

I know one of the reliable solution is avoid storing the object in static `HashMap`, but putting them in Bundle as `Parcelable`.

But, if for case it is not possible to put the class as `Parcelable`, as they are having file handle, thread handle, concurrent data structures, ... what is the strategy to overcome this?

I know quite a number of similar questions had been raised. But seems there is no good solution given. (See, even Google's own FAQ forget to mention storing in static HashMap doesn't work all the time)

Comment: *what is the strategy to overcome this?* - check before you access the data, if it's already available use it, if not retrieve it again.

Comment: Good question. I would try to convert critical data stored in the static HashMap to JSON and store in the preference onPause and restore  onResume. Not a neat solution but it may work

Comment: If the value that I need to pass around is only primitives or String and it is really important, I would choose to save it in database instead.

Comment: I'm more concern in onPause, as it can be triggered quite easily. (Rotation, Home press, ...) The static HashMap will not be cleared off all the time. So, it is pretty "waste" to run disk I/O write operation frequently to solve once-in-a-while problem. Is there any way to reduce the number of write operations? I'm not too concern in onResume, as we can check for data nullness, before decide to disk I/O read.

Comment: in that case why not put it in onDestroy instead of onPause? Since the object is not static, the object should remain until the activity is destroyed.

Comment: onDestroy is not guarantee called. You may experience data loss. If you long press on home, left swipe your app, then everything gone.

Comment: Static variables are also destroyed when your application is destroyed. The only place you can store data is in disk, say in a preference file or in the database.

Comment: The FAQ mentions the problem, albeit in general form: The first sentence of "Persistent Objects", all three methods before are affected, they are just showing different ways to access and organize global variables [the honest name]. The FAQ is the wrong place for this elementary discussion, IMHO. They should shorten the first part of the entry to two sentences ("You can use static fields as global variables. They can be destroyed according to the life cycle.").